# Laravel Form Request Errors are displayed as JSON on browser instead of HTML file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the latest laravel version 8.x

I have a basic CRUD dashboard for users and I use form requests to validate the post request when creating a new user.

When the validation fails, errors are displayed on the browser as JSON instead of HTML (blade) file with the error bag.

[image]

Feels like form requests are meant to use only on API endpoints?

Any way to make the form requests work on traditional HTML forms?

UPDATE #1

Controller code:

```
public function store(UserCreateRequest $request): \Illuminate\Http\Response
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        
        // Creation logic, unrelated to the question

        return response()->view('users.show', ['user' => $user]);
    }
```

UPDATE #2

The form used to make the request:

```
<form action="{{ route('users_store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="flex flex-col mb-4">
        <label for="name">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
        <input class="m-0" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="User name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
        @error('name')
        <span class="text-orange mt-2">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col mb-4">
        <label for="email">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
        <input class="m-0" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="{{ __('User email') }}" value="{{ old('email') }}">
        @error('email')
        <span class="text-orange mt-2">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col mb-4">
        <label for="password">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
        <input class="m-0" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="{{ __('User password') }}" value="{{ old('password') }}">
        @error('password')
        <span class="text-orange mt-2">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col mb-4">
        <label for="password_confirmation">{{ __('Password confirmation') }}</label>
        <input class="m-0" type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" placeholder="{{ __('Password confirmation') }}" value="">
        @error('password_confirmation')
        <span class="text-orange mt-2">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="flex items-center mt-8">
        <button type="submit" class="button m-0">{{ __('Create user') }}</button>
        <a href="{{ route('settings_users') }}" class="text-grayDark font-semibold ml-4 hover:underline">{{__('Cancel')}}</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

UPDATE #3

Request class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: @Espresso Done. See the update

Comment: Your validation method return a json response?

Comment: How are you sending the data to your desired CRUD ? It seems you are sending as a JSON, so the response will be a JSON too. Can you share that part please ?

Comment: @Espresso Thanks for the response, I add the request class

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks for the response, I added the HTML form code

Comment: @CecilyMiller Did you use the `web` or `api` file for your routes? You should use the web file. (I upvoted your question, not sure why you got downvoted by someone else.)

Comment: @LobsterBaz Thanks:) And yes, I'm using the `web` file. I thought myself as well that the issue is some middleware set it as JSON response but no :/ Also, I have tried to set the content type as text/html inside the `failedValidation` request method but no luck

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause?